# Asp.net mvc Setting up dynamic Docking with Css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, html, docking

Im trying to setup my asp.net mvc page like the following image:[image]

The header and bottom bar should always stay the same size and dock to the top and bottom of the page. In the middle is a infragistics jgrid that i want to always take up the center area of the page, so it should shrink and grow with the browser window.

So Im at a bit of a loss on how to dynamically change the div sizes and location when the browser window size changes.Any ideas/examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kdKCT/1/ i hope this will solve your problem. you can set the position property of header and footer to `fixed` so when your content scrolls while header and footer stay at the same place in your browser window.

Comment: Hi QQping, I think that is half my answer. I need to resize the infragistics jgrid the "Content" div to resize depending on the browser window as well. So I dont whether this is the fact of adding listener event on the window resize and changing the height of the grid accordingly. If this is even possible? Thanks